# Read data from HeidiSQL DB to servlet

Tags: servlets, heidisql

I am making a program where I can add data to the DB via servlet but I am not able to bring it back from the DB to the HTML page.

I am using a HTML page, some JS and two servlets: one for entering data in the DB, and this servlet for getting data back.

I am calling this servlet from a JS function, but I am not able to tell why the debbugger shows that it skips all the code. I am using eclipse IDE.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TodoDisplayServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TodoDisplayServlet")
public class TodoDisplayServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public TodoDisplayServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con1 = null;

        con1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tododb2","targarian","liger");

        String query1 =  "select fname, lname, email, pnum"  + "from tododb2";


            stmt = (PreparedStatement) con1.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query1);

            sb.append("<table>");
            while (rs.next()) {
                sb.append("<tr>");

                sb.append("<td>");
                rs.getString(1);
                sb.append("</td>");

                sb.append("<td>");
                rs.getString(2);
                sb.append("</td>");

                sb.append("<td>");
                rs.getString(3);
                sb.append("</td>");

                sb.append("<td>");
                rs.getString(4);
                sb.append("</td>");

                sb.append("</tr>");

            sb.append("</table>");
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            stmt.close();
            }


         PrintWriter writter = null;
            writter = response.getWriter();
          writter.println(sb.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide exactly what error you get for someone to be able to help you. Your query looks wrong though. You have no space between `pnum` and `from`.  Make it `select fname, lname, email, pnum from tododb2`. Also, from your connection string, it looks like tododb2 might be the name of your database. Is it also the name of the table you are trying to select those values from?

Comment: Thank you soo much.. it was the database name like you said.. its working now.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with tododb2 which was my database name and not my table name. thanks a lot mr. moose.